# Vertical side menus in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Does anyone know how to build menus just like [the one here](https://jqueryui.com/menu/#default) using IE6 (this almost works).

Perhaps some version of jquery-ui that works with IE6. I tried also [this menu](http://devinrolsen.com/pure-css-vertical-menu/) with [this css hover fix](http://devinrolsen.com/fix-css-pseudo-hover/) but in my case it did not fix and that menu does not work either.
I am trying to replace an old applet menu in an old system (i.e. 6 compatible) for something less difficult to maintain and I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Do you *really* need to support IE6 still?

Comment: Lets have a round of sympathy for all IE6 users in the world.

Comment: "some version of jquery-ui that works with IE6". So, Googling "jqueryui IE6" (I know, it was tricky to work out what to search for...) revealed, as the first result: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/ which says "As of 1.10.0, some portions of jQuery UI may not work properly in IE6. If you need to continue to support IE6, use the latest jQuery UI 1.9 release." You can download 1.9.2 at http://jqueryui.com/download/ . Make sure you have a compatible version of jQuery as well. P.S. You have my sympathy still having to support that tin-pot browser. I would have resigned in disgust.

Comment: Sorry guys, I really have to support I.E. 6 :(